# Python - MySQL Connector syntax error

Tags: python, mysql

This is probably something really simple, but I am going crazy trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here. My goal: perform a simple INSERT operation using Connector/Python to communicate with my MySQL database. My code:

```
def insert(title, artist, img):

    conn = mysql.connector.connect(***credentials***)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    title = title.lower().replace(' ', '_')
    path = 'img/' + title + '.png'
    sp.misc.imsave(path, img)

    add_img = ("INSERT INTO ref "
            "(song_title, artist, path) "
            "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")

    img_data = (title, artist, path)

    # execute and commit 
    cursor.execute(add_img, img_data)
    conn.commit()

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

This:
`insert("Back in Black Live Mono", "ACDC", img)`
Gives me:

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'references (song_title, artist, path) VALUES ('Back in'
Black Live Mono', 'ACDC',' at line 1`
```

The image saves successfully, but the INSERT statement is never executed. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417520/error-while-writing-to-a-mysql-wih-python-netcdf

Comment: Now that you've changed the code, please edit the question to include the new error message this returns.  There's no way your updated code can report an error about `references` when it no longer contains this word.

Comment: The weird thing is that it does report an error about `references`. That MySQL command must be cached or something, I'm going to restart my server and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Any luck?  I'd be surprised if MySQL was caching that query somewhere.  I suspect it's either a Python caching issue (try deleting `.pyc` files (Python 2) or `__pycache__` folders (Python 3)) or you're not running the code you think you are (try adding a line `print("test")` and see if that turns up in the output).

Comment: Sorry about that, quick dinner break. Yes, it worked! Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REFERENCES` is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).  If you want to use it as a table name you must quote it in backticks:

```
add_img = ("INSERT INTO `references` "
        "(song_title, artist, path) "
        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
```

Comment: I tried that and I also tried changing the table name to 'ref', and still no dice. That was a good call, but I guess was not the only problem.

Comment: Nevermind, this was the correct solution. For some reason Python kept my old query and was running that when I tried to run the new query. Thanks!